# Exiting from the bot between the intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

We have a dialogflow bot(Enterprise edition) consisting of some intents. I have also enabled slot filling for the intents.

Is there any way to exit from the middle of the intent leaving the remaining questions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [Dialogflow fulfillment library](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) should provide samples to help you with this. If you're using Node.js with Dialogflow v2's telephony gateway, Google Assistant and Alexa integrations, this should work:

```
  /**
   * Add a response or list of responses to be sent to Dialogflow and end the conversation
   * Note: Only supported on Dialogflow v2's telephony gateway, Google Assistant and Alexa integrations
   *
   * @param {RichResponse|string|RichResponse[]|string[]} responses (list) or single responses
   */

  end(responses) {
    this.client.end_(responses);
  }
```